# Python_Counting the number of rows corresponding to a certain value

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the total number of rows that have a specific value in a column. For example:
Temperature 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 10, 2

where the temperature is a column, and 2,4, etc. are the values in the column. I'm trying to count the total number of rows corresponding to the value 2.

Please help me to find a code for that.

Edit:
What I tried so far:
df.['temperature'].value_counts()
This gives me counts for all temperatures, but I only need the counts for temperatures less than or equal to 2.

Edit2:
Now I'm trying to count the same, but for specific a specific town. This is sample of what I have:
| Town.    | Temperature    |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Paris    | 2              |
| New York | 5              |
| Paris.   | 2.             |
| Paris    | 6.             |
| Paris    | 2.             |

I'm trying to find the total number of temperatures less than or equal to 2, but only for Paris.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what doesn't work?

Comment: You should include what code you've tried so far and its outcomes, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried df.['temperature'].value_counts() that is giving me the counts for all temperatures, but I only need the counts for temperatures less than or equal to 2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the edit2: you can try `df1 = df[df["temperature"]==2][df["town"]=="Paris"]`

This will return the dataframe match your condition, you can count on this dataframe by `df1.value_counts()`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!